# How do I add a php variable to a onclick function argument?

Tags: javascript, php

Beginner JS here.

I am trying to add a PHP variable to a Javascript onclick function. I converted the PHP variable to a JS variable just fine. However, when adding the JS variable to the function I'm not receiving the desired output.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
  js_logo_number = "<?php echo $logo_number; ?>";
</script>
<img src='<?php echo $image1[0]; ?>' onclick="openModal();currentSlide(js_logo_number)">
```

Comment: What is "_the desired output_"? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this :

```
<img src='<?php echo $image1[0]; ?>' onclick="openModal();currentSlide(<?php echo $logo_number; ?>)">
```

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me. Be sure you use a `let` or `const` (or the outdated `var`) prefix to declare `js_logo_number` a new variable. Also make sure that `$logo_number` is set like this:

```
<script>
let js_logo_number = <?php  isset($logo_number)?$logo_number:null; ?>;
</script>
```

Then make sure you convert it to an integer in Javascript, if that's how you want to use it:

```
function currentSlide(num){
  console.log('currentSlide fired', parseInt(num));
}
```

```js
let js_logo_number = "5";

function openModal(){
  console.log('openModal fired');
}

function currentSlide(num){
  console.log('currentSlide fired', parseInt(num));
}
```

```html
<img src='https://placekitten.com/200/200' onclick="openModal();currentSlide(js_logo_number)">
```

Comment: Can you say it works when you don't know what they expected result is supposed to be?

Comment: @JohnConde that's what the `isset()` and `parseInt()` are for.

Comment: @symlink. I was planning on using the PHP variable as an integer. I guess I shouldn't put the php variable in quotes.